# Best way to transform a list with a specific structure into a list of objects

Tags: javascript

This is the list that contains in the first key figure, all the attributes of my desired object, and in the later key figures, contains the value for each attribute in the line.:

```
[
  [
    "goalId",
    "holderId",
    "balance",
    "taxes",
    "netBalance",
    "investmentIncome"
  ],
  [
    "1",
    "1",
    "33333333",
    "150",
    "150",
    "1"
  ],
  [
    "5",
    "5",
    "1000",
    "150",
    "150",
    "1"
  ],
  [
    "7",
    "7",
    "1000",
    "150",
    "150",
    "1"
  ],
  [
    "11",
    "12",
    "1000",
    "150",
    "150",
    "1"
  ],
  [
    ""
  ]
]
```

And I want to turn the above list into a list of objects like this:

```
[ 
      { 
         "goalId":1,
         "holderId":1,
         "balance":33333333,
         "taxes":150,
         "netBalance":150,
         "investmentIncome":1
      },
      { 
         "goalId":5,
         "holderId":5,
         "balance":1000,
         "taxes":150,
         "netBalance":150,
         "investmentIncome":1
      },
      { 
         "goalId":7,
         "holderId":7,
         "balance":1000,
         "taxes":150,
         "netBalance":150,
         "investmentIncome":1
      },
      { 
         "goalId":11,
         "holderId":12,
         "balance":1000,
         "taxes":150,
         "netBalance":150,
         "investmentIncome":1
      }
]
```

I've already done it, but I think there's a better way to do it. The code was like this:

```
// Assuming that the variable already has the list loaded

const attributes = unformattedList[0];
unformattedList.splice(0, 1);
const arrayOfObjects = unformattedList.map(rawValue => {
  const object = {};
  rawValue.map((value, index) => {
    object[attributes[index]] = value;
  });
  return object;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `.map()` if your sole use-case for it is to iterate and cause side-effects - `.forEach()` is better for that task. However, you can still use `.map()` for this type of problem if you use it as intended (i.e use the new array it returns). First, you can get the keys of your objects by popping the first element from you array using `.shift()`. Then, you can `.map()` each inner array of values to an object (formed using `Object.assign()`), which contains all your values from the inner array:

```js
const arr = [[ "goalId", "holderId", "balance", "taxes", "netBalance", "investmentIncome" ], [ "1", "1", "33333333", "150", "150", "1" ], [ "5", "5", "1000", "150", "150", "1" ], [ "7", "7", "1000", "150", "150", "1" ], [ "11", "12", "1000", "150", "150", "1" ], [ "" ]];
const keys = arr.shift();
const res = arr.filter(({length}) => length > 1).map(
  vals => Object.assign({}, ...vals.map((v, i) => ({[keys[i]]: +v})))
)
console.log(res);
```

Above I am also using `.filter(({length}) => length > 1))` to remove the uneeded `[""]` from your array. This will also remove empty arrays as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. Saved my day from planting a bad code in the system